# Smart way to check if every entry in a object is not null or undefined

Tags: javascript, object

I have got an object, that may look like this:

```
{
  address: {
    street: undefined,
    country: 'GB'
  },
  givenname: 'Marko',
  surname: null,
}
```

I want to know if all fields are set or if at least one is null. Is there a smarter / shorter way to dot his in javascript than

```
address.street != null && address.country != null && givenname != null && surname != null
```

Maybe something that looks like this:

```
// this could return true or false?
nullCheck(address.street, address.country, givenname, surname)
```

Comment: You don't have to explicitly check against `!= null`. You can rely on implicit conversion to Boolean and a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) check: `if(address.streetl && address.country && givenname && surname)`

Comment: @ScottMarcus but empty strings will not pass this check.

Comment: Your title is kind of misleading, since there are no `const`s in your code. Your property names are also invalid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining if all attributes on a javascript object are null or an empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709636/determining-if-all-attributes-on-a-javascript-object-are-null-or-an-empty-string)

Comment: The given object is not valid. The `.` cannot by used in JavaScript identifiers. Do you mean `{ "address.street": undefined, "address.country": 'GB' }` or `{ address: { street: undefined, country: 'GB' } }`?

Comment: This is very similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63031063/697154

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is the typical way to go actually. Works fine specially if you have typings, like with TypeScript.

The second one is just the same but with a bit of overhead (each time you enter/exit a function, adss a bit of overhead), although is really small overhead only noticeable when you have tons of iterations. You can detect the arguments dynamically:

```js
const nullobj = {
    value1: "yay",
    value2: "",
    value3: 23,
    value4: null
};
const obj = {
    value1: "yay",
    value2: "",
    value3: 23,
    value4: "ok"
};

function checkArgumentsNull(...args) {
    for (let v of args) {
        if (v == null) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log("nullobj:", checkArgumentsNull(nullobj.value1, nullobj.value2, nullobj.value3, nullobj.value4));
console.log("obj:", checkArgumentsNull(obj.value1, obj.value2, obj.value3, obj.value4));
```

But if you are going to check dynamically for arguments, you can check dynamically for properties, which is easier. **Just saw your edit** and this one can be easily converted to a **recursive** one that will **check for sub-objects**. Actually all functions here can be converted to recursive ones following this principle:

```js
const nullobj = {
    value1: {
        ok: "ok",
        notok: null
    },
    value2: "",
    value3: 23,
    value4: "ok"
};
const obj = {
    value1: {
        ok: "ok",
        notok: "no"
    },
    value2: "",
    value3: 23,
    value4: "ok"
};

function checkPropertiesNull(obj) {
    for (let v in obj) {
        if (obj[v] == null || (typeof obj[v] === "object" && checkPropertiesNull(obj[v]))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log("nullobj:", checkPropertiesNull(nullobj));
console.log("obj:", checkPropertiesNull(obj));
```

And for the sake of modern JavaScript, you can even pass an iterator, and you can check whatever iterable object you can imagine of (object, arrays, maps, sets, etc):

```js
const nullobj = {
    value1: "yay",
    value2: "",
    value3: 23,
    value4: null
};
const obj = {
    value1: "yay",
    value2: "",
    value3: 23,
    value4: "ok"
};
const nullarr = ["ok", "yay", null];
const arr = ["ok", "yay", "yay2"];

function checkIteratorNull(it) {
    for (let v of it) {
        if (v == null) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log("nullobj:", checkIteratorNull(Object.values(nullobj)));
console.log("obj:", checkIteratorNull(Object.values(obj)));
console.log("nullarr:", checkIteratorNull(nullarr));
console.log("arr:", checkIteratorNull(arr));
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is.
You can use the *Object* data type, and the *includes* array method like this:

```
Object.values(your_object).includes(null)
```

This will return *true* if your object contains **at least one** *null* element and *false* if it doesn't contain any.

This answer only works for 1 level deep objects.

[Object Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)
[Array.includes Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`every`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_every.asp) method, given a list of variables to check, with a callback that checks for null.

```js
let address = {
    street: undefined,
    country: 'GB'
  },
  givenname = 'Marko',
  surname = null;

console.log([address.street, address.country, givenname, surname].every(e => e !== null))

surname = "blah"

console.log([address.street, address.country, givenname, surname].every(e => e !== null))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.some`

```js
const hasAnEmptyValue = (obj) => Object.values(obj).some(value => !value)

const obj1 = {
  address: null,
  givenname: 'Rick',
  surname: 'Sanchez',
}

const obj2 = {
  address: 'Argentina',
  givenname: 'Rick',
  surname: 'Sanchez',
}
    
console.log(hasAnEmptyValue(obj1))

console.log(hasAnEmptyValue(obj2))
```

Comment: I'm curious. Why `!Boolean(value)` and not simply `!value`. Is there any moment where they return different values? Just to know.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález yeah, should be the same. I was using `Boolean` because at first I was doing: `.some(Boolean)` but then I changed to return `!Boolean`